# autocomplete No Result found in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, autocomplete, eloquent

I have two table "patient" and "booking" table, and there is a relationship "One to Many" between them, I want to set up a search form in an index_booking page where a user can type a patient_name on it and auto complete show all patient_name from patient table according to WHERE Condition.

This is Booking Model

```
class Booking extends Eloquent
{

    public function patient()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient'); 
    }

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

This is Patient Model

```
class Patient extends Eloquent
{
    public function booking()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Booking'); 
    }

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

And i used this code in index page of booking

```
{!! Form::text('search_text', null, array('placeholder' => 'Search Text','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'search_text')) !!}
```

i used this code in Booking Controller to make autocomplete to show data 
from patient table:

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request)
{
    $patients = Patient::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
        ->where('patient_name', 'like', "&{$request->get('term')}&")
        ->get();

    if ($patients->isEmpty()) {
        return ['value' => 'No Result Found', 'id' => ''];
    }

    return $patients->map(function ($patient) {
        return [
            'id'    => $patient->id,
            'value' => $patient->patient_name,
        ];
    });
}
```

And this is Route

```
Route::get('autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'BookingController@index'));
Route::get('searchajax',array('as'=>'searchajax','uses'=>'BookingController@autoComplete'));
```

Javascript code is

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function() {
    src = "{{ route('searchajax') }}";
     $("#search_text").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);

                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,

    });
});

</script>
```

when i type any patient name in search box i received a message No Result Found

this is the validator in booking controller :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //Validate Data
        $this->validate($request, [
              'patient_id'=> 'required|integer',             
               'booking_date'=> 'required|max:255',
               'tybe'=> 'required',
               'value'=>'required',
               'doctor_name',
               'patient_history',
               'pharma',
               'complaint',
               'diagnosis',
               'recomind',
               'prescription',
               'notes',
               'document',
               'by',



            ]);  

               //Insert Data to Database
               $booking = new Booking;

               $booking->patient_id = $request->patient_id;
               $booking->booking_date = $request->booking_date;
               $booking->tybe  = $request->tybe;
               $booking->value = $request->value;
               $booking->doctor_name = $request->doctor_name;
               $booking->patient_history = $request->patient_history;
               $booking->pharma = $request->pharma;
               $booking->complaint = $request->complaint;
               $booking->diagnosis = $request->diagnosis;
               $booking->recomind = $request->recomind;
               $booking->prescription = $request->prescription;
               $booking->notes = $request->notes;
               $booking->document = $request->document;
               $booking->by = $request->by;

               $booking->save();



               //to save multi selection Tags ,dont foget to add [] after -> tags in create post page then write this code here
               //$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

               //Show Flash Message

                Session::flash('success','تم حفظ البياانات');

               //Redirect to another Page 

               return redirect()->route('booking.index');
    }
```

Comment: Wilcards for SQL's LIKE operator are percent signs, not ampersands.

Comment: could you explain it Please?

Comment: Your `->where('patient_name', 'like', "&{$request->get('term')}&")` line produces SQL query with `WHERE patient_name LIKE '&something&'` and it should be `WHERE patient_name LIKE '%something%'`

Comment: Yes , You saved my Time, thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. I wasn't sure if that was the only problem in your code, so I prefered to try with a comment first. I added it as the answer so you can upvote and select it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL's syntax for matching with `LIKE` operator is:

```
WHERE `column` LIKE '%needle%'
```

Your code, on the other hand, produces the following:

```
WHERE `column` LIKE '&needle&'
```

Which is virtually the same as if you had typed:

```
WHERE `column` = '&needle&'
```

So what you need to do is to replace `&` with `%` in the following line:

```
->where('patient_name', 'like', "&{$request->get('term')}&")
```

Comment: i accept your answer but i cant upvote it because i dont have enough reputation , thank you again :)

Comment: Sorry @Robo Robok , but when i submit form i receive an error message says : The patient id field is required.!!

Comment: You probably have such a requirement in your validator and maybe it expects another field name.

Comment: i updated the question and added the Validator , could you check it please ?

Comment: @EsamMohamed From these snippets it looks good to me, the problem is somewhere else I think. Do you have other validators?

Comment: No other validator for booking form, but there are validator for other forms, is this code correct? {!! Form::text('search_text', null, array('placeholder' => 'Search Text','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'search_text')) !!}

Comment: Make sure your routes are okay, because it's a little quirky. You have `/autocomplete` route pointing to `index()` method and `/searchajax` route pointing to `autoComplete()` method.

Comment: Yes, what are you suggest?

Comment: Well, `/autocomplete` route would be better pointing to the `autocomplete()` method, that would make it easier to maintain. I could take a look at your project, but I think we need to talk privately. You'd need to show me your entire code.

Comment: Sorry @ Robo Robok  i dont have enough reputation to chat wit you :(

Comment: Do you have Skype?

Comment: Yes i Have , Wait

Comment: my account on skype :  esam.m7md@hotmail.com